# Does W3C Validation (Web Validation) really make any difference to your site?

Tags: html

Does displaying the various validation marks on your website make a difference?
For Example

**- HTML Validation**

**- W3C CSS Validation**

**- W3C XHTML Validation**

What is the communities opinion on this area?
Are Browsers honouring the validations anyway?

Comment: Voted to close as "off topic" - this is a question for the webmaster proposal, not the web application one.

Comment: @Kinopiko is correct. Web Apps is about *using* websites, not building or running them. Vote to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two reasons, one human the other computer.

The human reason - it shows visitors that you care about these things and that your site is going to be well written and not try to exploit their browsers. It doesn't say anything about the content though :)

The computer reason - it means that your site/application should render correctly and consistently in any browser be it IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera.

Comment: "...your site/application should render correctly..." assuming that browsers are all sticking to standards ;)

Comment: @adambox - hence the *should* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Advertising that your sites is using valid HTML is much like a car dealer advertising that his cars can drive.

I don't think there is much point in displaying to your users what type of HTML is made to build the page and that it's valid. Most users wont know the difference anyways.

But the sites that actually does the validation can is a good tool for a developer. It's a quick way to check if you have made any mistakes in your markup and can avoid browser rendering the site differently.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying those marks? No.

However sites that can be read with screen readers, with tags that are well-formed, that work on multiple different devices (e.g. browsers, cell phones, ipads, etc.) as well as multiple browsers on pc's.  Those make a difference because they actually increase usage.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little old school and users don't care about that or they don't know what are these, but i recommend validation in order to have a clean code and a correct workflow.